# My Computer has been running slowly and has started stuttering during games it could previously run with ease. What is wrong?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, performance, gaming, fps

I have a gaming laptop. It has run great in the past, being able to run nearly any game. Now, it sometimes struggles to run light games. Sometimes it will run fine for 30 mins but then it will stutter and have a massive fps drop. I then turn off my computer for a few hours, and then it runs it fine for 30 minutes, and the process repeats. I have done multiple virus scans, I have tried to update my graphics card, and I have tried to help the ventilation and cooling. None of these have fixed the problem.  I also normally use a second monitor, and when I unplug it from the laptop, it sometimes helps, but not by much, so I think the problem is with the graphics card. Here are the specs of the laptop | processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz   2.21 GHz | RAM: 16.0 GB (15.9 GB usable) |  It is a strix gl704gw by ASUS. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Though you tried to help ventilation, have you actually monitored CPU and GPU temps prior to and while you're encountering these issues? I've had laptops in the past where the fan is running, but not at the correct speed which would eventually cause overheating.

Comment: Is it possible that a scheduled task is kicking in after a period of time?

Answer (score 1):

Windows rot. Completely blank the drive and re-install.

Also probably a good time to dismantle the thing, blow any dust out of fans and fins, and apply fresh thermal paste to heatsinks.

Answer (score -1):

Try typing %temp% on the left bottom search of your taskbar and deleting all contents of this folder .

Basically this procedure is just for cleaning temporary files from your system.

I hope that helps. Let me know.

Regards,
Andrei

Comment: The temp folder does not contain "cache" files.  Although it is a good idea to do this from time to time, this is bad/incorrect advice for the problem at hand and will accomplish nothing.  I am glad that you are trying to help though.